# In Windows XP Task Manager, shows 150+ processes running?

Tags: windows-xp, process, task-manager

Almost every morning my laptop slows or stops. When I bring up task manager it usually shows something between 80 and 150 line items called Task Manager, and I have to close them down one at a time to get back to normal function, which seems to require about 45 processes enabled.

I am a single user with very low level programs running...no games or demanding software.
How can I cure this problem please?

Comment: Does this happen at the same time every morning, even when the computer is left on (eg overnight)? or do you just mean it happens when you turn your computer on (which is usually in the morning)?

Answer (score 2):

Click Start -> run

type msconfig, click the Startup tab

Click the button that says "disable all" and reboot

This will disable all the startup processes. After reboot, see if the problem still exists.

If no more issues, one of the processes that is running at startup was the cause. You can re-enable them one by one to determine which is the culprit.

If the problem persists after doing this, scan for bad stuff with this http://www.malwarebytes.org

not a bad idea to do that scan either way, really.